# Model not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

I've tried setting up a form validation that would ensure that at least 1 and at most 3 tags must be included in the form. But it isn't working as an empty form is still processed, but a form with 4 comma-seperated tags is validated correctly.

**Controller**

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  current_user.tag(@product, :with => params[:product][:tag_list], :on => :tags)
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    redirect_to :root, :notice => "Added"
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Your tags" %> <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :value => @product.tags_from(current_user) %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Change" %></p>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<% end %>
```

**Model**

```
validate :required_info
validates_size_of :tag_list,
                  :maximum => 3

private

  def required_info
    if( tag_list.empty? and description.empty? )
      errors.add_to_base "Add one"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( tag_list.empty? and description.empty? )
  errors.add_to_base "Add one"
end
```

Just looking at this part of the model, I think you'd rather do `if(tag_list.empty? or description.empty?)` because you want both of them to be filled.

For the second validation, I'm not an `act_as_taggable` user so I can't answer you now.

Comment: Aha. It was set up as a logical and because the description was intentionally left empty but now that it isn't, a logical or was needed for this validation to work. Thanks for the brainspark.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom validation:

```
validates :tag_list_length

private

def tag_list_length
   errors.add(:tag_list, "Must include at least one and no more than three tags") unless tag_list.length.between?(1,3)
end
```